# Error: Unknown Return Type, The return type for the following stored procedures could not be detected

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I am using the following technologies:

1. MS SQL 2008 R2
2. Visual Studio 2010
3. Silverlight project
4. LINQ to SQL

When dragging a stored procedure into the data model, and the stored procedure returns an OUTPUT parameter, it works fine. However when the stored procedure returns a result set created with dynamic SQL I receive the following error:

**"Unknown Return Type, The return type for the following stored procedure could not be detected."**

If the stored procedure does not use dynamic SQL, it works fine. 
(For example: SELECT column1 from table2)

The stored procedure however uses dynamic SQL to query a specified view for the data. Simplified below for illustration purposes:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetViewData
    @ViewName nvarchar(150)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(MAX)

    SET @Sql = 'SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM' + @ViewName
    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
END
```

Instead of returning the result set directly, I can place the result set into a temp table. This however gives the same error.

According to the article from Ritesh, when placing the result set into a table type variable this should do the trick, however this is not possible in dynamic sql as the scope is only within the executed dynamic sql.

Ritesh's article: 
http://riteshkk2000.blogspot.com/2010/08/error-unknown-return-type-return-types.html

Upon further investigation I realized that the meta data received by LINQ to SQL does not contain the necessary information to define the type.

Apparently with SQL 2012 this can be resolved by using "WITH RESULTS SET" to actually define the meta data manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by creating another stored procedure, calling GetViewData without using dynamic SQL and populating a table type variable:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CallGetViewData
    @ViewName nvarchar(150)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ViewResultSet TABLE
    (
        column1 nvarchar(50),
        column2 int,
        column3 float
    )

    INSERT INTO @ViewResultSet
        EXEC GetViewData @ViewName

    SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM @ViewResultSet
END
```

Now when I drag stored procedure CallGetViewData into the data model, it detects the return type correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One trick you can try is to manually create a model that represents the shape of the object that the Stored Proc will return. Then using the designer, don't drag the proc into the method pane, but rather drop it on the type you created manually. LINQ to SQL will then use that class as the result type.

If you already have the method defined for the stored proc, you can change the Return Type using the F4 property window to any type that matches the result shape that you've defined in the model.